# When to change cell constraints for automatic cell height for iOS 8?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

My cell has an image which is part of the component for determining the height of it. It has a constant height constraint defined on the Storyboard and an outlet to it on the code.

I am trying to use iOS 8's automatic height.

On `viewDidLoad` I have this line: `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

A have also implemented the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method on the delegate.

The problem is I want to update the height constant when setting up the cell for display, but this doesn't seem to work because its height has already been calculated at this point. So I get this error on the log:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faed0854440 V:[winninapp.ScoreView:0x7faed08574d0(6)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faed085b020 V:[UIImageView:0x7faed085ae10(211)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faed0866700 V:|-(0)-[app.ScoreView:0x7faed08574d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7faed085cf90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faed08667f0 V:[app.ScoreView:0x7faed08574d0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7faed085e180]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faed0866890 V:[UIImageView:0x7faed085ae10]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7faed085cf90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faed08668e0 V:[UIView:0x7faed085e180]-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7faed085ae10]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faed0867d50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7faed085cf90(44)]>"
)
```

What's the correct place to update the height constant for the cell?

I have tried calling these methods after updating the constant, but with no luck:

```
setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
setNeedsLayout()
layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way I finally got working without getting conflict warnings and the cell is displaying correctly was by removing the previous constraint and adding a new one.

I did this because I have changed the constraint from height to a kind of ratio and you cannot set the multiplier for a constraint and it ended up working.

I just added this to the constraint observer:

```
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailRatio: NSLayoutConstraint! {
  willSet {
    videoThumbnail?.removeConstraint(thumbnailRatio)
    videoThumbnail?.addConstraint(newValue)
  }
}
```

By doing this way there is no need to call `setNeedsLayout()` or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

when i set up a simple tableviewcontroller with the following content (heightconstraint is the imageview's height constraint) everything works as expected:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.heightConstraint.constant = arc4random_uniform(50) + 20;

    return cell;
}
```

here is what it looks like:

[image: simulator screenshot]

Comment: Apart from returning properly calculated estimated sizes for the cell views, you're doing exactly what want and it seems to be working. That's strange...

Comment: i noticed that i nevertheless get some constraint warnings when i scroll and cells have to be reloaded. to make that warnings go away i changed the bottom constraint's priority (bottom of the image view to the bottom of the cell) from 1000 (required) to 750 (high).

Comment: I got it working by removing the constraint and adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

you can give this line

self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension 
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = expected max height

in viewDidLoad.

set number of rows to 0 and NSLinebreakMode to Word wrap or char wrap

```
[cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adjusting a height constraint in code, try constraining your image view to the top/bottom of the cell. The cell will size properly based on the size of the image view. You might need to change the fit of your image view to fill so that it shows the entire image.

Comment: My views already have constraints that define the cell height. The problem is that I have to download the image I will display, but I have the size before hand and want to set the size accordingly.

Comment: If you have a height constraint on the cell, I'm suggesting you remove that and instead rely on constraining your image view to the cell top and bottom. The cell should dynamically change height based on what image you put in it. I'm suggesting you shouldn't explicitly set constraints on the cell height.

Comment: Oh... I see. I don't have an explicit constraint on the cell height, though. That one on the log is generated by the table view.